# Visual Studio Code

Tags: remix, tokens

Can I use **visual studio** code for the *testing* and *debugging* of my smart contact, remix doesn’t seem to work for me

Comment: Already answered here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/161862/91017.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly use [Visual Studio Code Editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for testing and debugging your smart contacts using tools like [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) (based purely on Solidity), [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) (based on Javascript) etc., according to your preferences.

I would recommend following [Patrick Collins](https://twitter.com/PatrickAlphaC)' amazing tutorials on his [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/@PatrickAlphaC), such as:

1. [Intro to Foundry | The FASTEST Smart Contract Framework](https://youtu.be/fNMfMxGxeag)
2. [Build and Deploy Smart Contracts using Hardhat](https://youtu.be/GBc3lBrXEBo)

And, his entire playlists on:

1. [Blockchain Developer, Solidity, Foundry Full Course 2023](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4Rj_WH6yLgWe7TxankiqkrkVKXIwOP42&si=doiCXRPsnxCXKa-k)
2. [Smart Contract Developer, Solidity, and Hardhat](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4Rj_WH6yLgUNMj5sfJK6cQ2DJUQR6Fkc&si=3GwQ2qJhdJ2B68J8)

Moreover, you can also join [Cyfrin Updraft](https://updraft.cyfrin.io/) for all of his amazing courses, and that too for free.